# 'error' event is called after 'end' event?

Tags: node.js, http2

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');
function APICall(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        const client = http2.connect('https://localhost:8443', {
            ca: fs.readFileSync('localhost-cert.pem')
        });
        client.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));

        const req = client.request({ ':path': '/' });

        req.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log("error",error)
            reject("Could not connect with server");
        });

        req.setEncoding('utf8');
        let data = '';
        req.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; });
        req.on('end', () => {
            console.log(`\n${data}`);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

I have created an http2 client (using the example provided in the official website except I have used it inside a Promise ). The problem I am having is that even when my server is unavailable, The end event is called before the error event. So instead of rejecting with error, the promise is resolved with empty data. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: isn't the library deprecated? `Use the built-in module in node 9.0.0 or newer, instead` can you check if same thing happening with the newer version?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I am using the inbuilt module itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So according to the [`http2/core.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/http2/core.js):

> // Upon creation, **the Http2Session takes ownership of the socket. The session
>
>   // may not be ready to use immediately if the socket is not yet fully connected.
>
>   // In that case, the Http2Session will wait for the socket to connect. Once
>
>   // the Http2Session is ready, it will emit its own 'connect' event.**
>   //
>   // The Http2Session.goaway() method will send a GOAWAY frame, signalling
>   // to the connected peer that a shutdown is in progress. Sending a goaway
>   // frame has no other effect, however.
>   //
>   // Calling session.destroy() will tear down the Http2Session immediately,
>   // making it no longer usable. Pending and existing streams will be destroyed.
>   // The bound socket will be destroyed. Once all resources have been freed up,
>   // the 'close' event will be emitted. Note that pending streams will be
>   // destroyed using a specific "ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL" error. Existing open
>   // streams will be destroyed using the same error passed to session.destroy()
>   //
>   // **If destroy is called with an error, an 'error' event will be emitted
>
>   // immediately following the 'close' event.**
>   //
>   // The socket and Http2Session lifecycles are tightly bound. Once one is
>   // destroyed, the other should also be destroyed. When the socket is destroyed
>   // with an error, session.destroy() will be called with that same error.
>   // Likewise, when session.destroy() is called with an error, the same error
>   // will be sent to the socket.

I think this is the expected behaviour where first the stream is `closed` and then `error` is emitted.

According to the above doc, I have added one `connect` event to see what is happening. When The server is unavailable it doesn't emit the `connect` event otherwise it does.

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');
function APICall(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        const client = http2.connect('http://localhost:8443', {
            // ca: fs.readFileSync('localhost-cert.pem')
        });
        client.on('error', (err) => console.error('client error'));

        const req = client.request({ ':path': '/' });

        client.on('connect', ()=>console.log('connect'))

        req.on('error', (error) => {
            reject("Could not connect with server");
        });

        req.setEncoding('utf8');
        let data = '';
        req.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk; });
        req.on('end', () => {
            console.log('ended');
            console.log(`\n${data}`);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

When http://localhost:8443 was **up**:

```
connect
ended
```

When http://localhost:8443 was **down**:

```
ended
client error
```

So, you can check using the `connect` event if there will be `data` or not.

**Note:** this is my opinion reading the source code, I don't know if this is correct or not. Feel free to edit the answer and improve it.